# WordPress load-scripts.php encoding issue

Tags: updates, encoding

After updating to Wordpress 4.7, the WordPress load-scripts.php is producing the following result. We are unable to identify the cause of this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: please provide your PHP version?

Comment: The server is running PHP 7.0.14

Comment: Are you running this on Windows, and what Browser, please?

Comment: It's a linux server and All browsers have the same issue

Comment: Do you get any web server errors when you create the request ? I think the problem you have is on Apache side.

Comment: No errors from server but browser has the following errors: http://i.imgur.com/yvz0IWp.png

Comment: Do you deregister jQuery at some point? Are you testing localy?

Comment: Have you tried to restart the web server and test again &mdash; does deleting your cookies from for that domain and clearing the cache help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916987/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal-load-scripts-php1

Comment: Every question that produces this amount of effort deserves the upvote!

Comment: Restarting the server didn't help :-(

Comment: Another strange thing that I noticed was when I've changed the version value from the get query, the issue is gone but it came again when I've refreshed the browser. http://i.imgur.com/Jj0dqwc.gif

Comment: This is typically a caching problem. You may have different caching levels @Soumith. Try to understand this further.

Comment: I update my the answer, to possible summarize your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the request header you get in your browser? It should follow this form:

```
File: load-scripts.php
56: header("Etag: $wp_version");
57: header('Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=UTF-8');
58: header('Expires: ' . gmdate( "D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $expires_offset ) . ' GMT');
59: header("Cache-Control: public, max-age=$expires_offset");
```

The request header is OK. I can confirm I saw similar problems on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916987/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal-load-scripts-php1), and these were solved via clearing the cache or opening the site in incognito Browser. I don't understand this problem so I need level up. Anyone?

---

> Another strange thing that I noticed was when I've changed the version value from the get query, the issue is gone but it came again when I've refreshed the browser. i.imgur.com/Jj0dqwc.gif

This looks like the caching problem. Caching in WordPress may affect you on:

1. Web browser lever
2. WordPress application level
3. Web server software or some proxy level

Typically the web server level you control via the .htaccess file, or web server config instructions

WordPress application level you control with some plugins you installed

And Web server software or some proxy level is based on what helper caching applications you installed on your Web Server.

For 2. and 3. you will certainly have the refresh option. 
Since when you alter the numbers at the end you the problem is gone, it is obvious this is a caching problem.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: You can open your page in incognito and let me know if this helps?

Comment: I have tried it in incognito, but still we are having the same result. We are having issue similar to 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916987/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal-load-scripts-php1 Tried all the answers from that question but still same result.

Comment: @Soumith, have you tried to restart Apache, and please let me know the other feedback I requested. We haven't had something similar on wpso.